# 2 promisses together returning null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

im making 2 requests, but when i get the values from the result if i call the variable outside the promise it get null, but since i depend the requrest result of 2 different promisses and also i need the execute a funcion based on the result of each promise i have no idea how can i resolve it.

My code controller:

```
$scope.originLatLong = null;
    $scope.destinationLatLong = null;

    //Get LAT and LONG from origin and destionation http://something/{Code}
    $http.get('something/getLatLng/'+$scope.originAirport).then(function(response){
        $scope.originLatLong = response.data; //doesnt return null

    });

$http.get('something/'+$scope.destinationAirport).then(function(response){
        $scope.destinationLatLong = response.data; //doesnt return null

    });

console.log($scope.originLatLong) //returns null
console.log($scope.destinationLatLong) //returns null
var distanceTotal = calculate($scope.destinationLatLong,$scope.originLatLong);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$scope.originLatLong = null;
$scope.destinationLatLong = null;

$http.get('something/getLatLng/'+$scope.originAirport).then(function(response){
    $scope.originLatLong = response.data;
    return $http.get('something/'+$scope.destinationAirport)
})
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.destinationLatLong = response.data;
    var distanceTotal = calculate($scope.destinationLatLong,$scope.originLatLong);
})
```

or if you need the distanceTotal outside .then(), declare it before the http calls:

```
$scope.originLatLong = null;
$scope.destinationLatLong = null;
var distanceTotal;

$http.get('something/getLatLng/'+$scope.originAirport).then(function(response){
    $scope.originLatLong = response.data;
    return $http.get('something/'+$scope.destinationAirport)
})
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.destinationLatLong = response.data;
    distanceTotal = calculate($scope.destinationLatLong,$scope.originLatLong);
})
```

Edit with explanation of original issue:

The `$http` calls are asynchronous, which means that the browser makes the requests, and the code after them continues running while the browser is waiting for a response from the server. This means that the order the code was executed in in your example was something like

```
$http call
The other $http call
console.log($scope.originLatLong)
console.log($scope.destinationLatLong)
var distanceTotal = calculate($scope.destinationLatLong,$scope.originLatLong);
$scope.originLatLong = response.data;
$scope.destinationLatLong = response.data;
```

Seeing how the variables are still null/undefined at the console.log()s, it's easy to see why the console.logs are undefined.

Another edit due to confusion:

You can't assume `distanceTotal` to be defined outside the `.then()` function. The only guaranteed place it's going to be defined in is inside `then()`.

Comment: Thanks Fissio, could you tell me what i was doing wrong or why didnt work?

Comment: Hello, i made a console.log(distanceTotal) outside the promises and nothing shows, gave me a undefined"

Comment: Check my edit; the issue is likely the same. You need to put the code using the `distanceTotal` inside the `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has multiple promises and you want to use both the responses together, I would solve this using `$q.all`.

All we need to do is create an array of promises. And with `$q.all`, we can get both the promises' response in one `.then()`. Here's how:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push($http.get('something/getLatLng/'+$scope.originAirport));
promises.push($http.get('something/'+$scope.destinationAirport));

$q.all(promises).then(function(response) {
  $scope.originLatLong = response[0].data;
  $scope.destinationLatLong = response[1].data;

  console.log($scope.originLatLong) 
  console.log($scope.destinationLatLong) 
  var distanceTotal = calculate($scope.destinationLatLong, $scope.originLatLong);
  ...
});
```